# How can I read MANY json objects from a file in Java?

Tags: java, json, jsonreader

The corresponding methods of `JsonReader` reader are followed by the rule that "this method needs to be called only once for a reader instance." Is there any standard tool to read from stream until it ends?

Comment: Good stuff! Regarding the first option. For technical reasons I'd like to stay within JSR-353. Regarding the second one. Is it guaranteed that InputStream will remember the place until which it was read the previous time? The matter of fact it should, but is it explicitly stated in any documentation?

Comment: (transferred my comments to an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to repetitively construct multiple `JsonReader`s around the same `InputStream` / `Reader`.  As long as you don't do anything else on the stream and as long as the parser doesn't read ahead, each successive parser should pick up where the last left off. Note that whether it might read ahead is undefined and may be implementation specific. Also note that it's common for parser implementations to close the stream/reader that they are given and you may need to suppress this by using a simple stream/reader wrapper that blocks close, like this:

```
Json.createReader(new NoCloseInputStream(myInputStream));
```

Otherwise, try a different parser. I have a [FOSS JSON parser](http://tech.dolhub.com/code/JsonParser) that can read a stream of discreet objects on my web site.

<strike>Also, the documentation of `JsonReader` says the `read()` method ***need*** only be called once; it doesn't say it ***must*** only be called once, so it's worth trying to call `read()` repeatedly to see if it works.</strike> Nevermind; the methods are documented to throw an `IllegalStateException` if any of the `read`, `readObject`, `readArray` or `close` methods are called more than once.

Comment: "Also note that it's common for parser implementations to close the stream/reader that they are given". It certainly throws an exception but not about closed stream. `javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 1 096 at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0)`